# Using React Photo Gallery with images files instead of images from URL

Tags: reactjs, firebase, image-gallery, photo-gallery

I am trying to use the following package for image gallery in my react app:

https://github.com/neptunian/react-photo-gallery

The images that I have are not from some URL, as shown in this example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-bassi-5vn3lvz2n4?from-embed=&file=/index.js:204-210

I tried to store them in a folder in my react application, and save a list of them and send this list to the Gallery as parameter, but the gallery doesn't display those images, only from URL images.

example of the list, Only the first image that is from URL is getting shown:

```
const photos = [
    {
        src: "https://source.unsplash.com/Dm-qxdynoEc/800x799",
        width: 4,
        height: 3
    },
    {
        src: "../assets/PowerToolsRentalsImages/hammers/bosch-gbh-11de/BoschGBH11de.jpg",
        width: 4,
        height: 3
    },
    {
        src: "../assets/PowerToolsRentalsImages/hammers/bosch-gbh-11de/BoschHammer11.png",
        width: 1,
        height: 1
    },
    {
        src: "../assets/PowerToolsRentalsImages/hammers/bosch-gbh-11de/BoschHammerRental.jpg",
        width: 3,
        height: 4
    }
];

export default photos;
```

this is how it looks in my app:

[image]

Source URL that is generated in the DOM:
[image]

Comment: Probably an error with your bundler config (eg webpack or other) on your assets path.

Comment: I tested the path by regular importing the image and showing it, and the path is ok...

Comment: What is the src url in the generated DOM when you inspecting your app ?

Comment: I have edited the question and added a picture with the URL from the DOM

Comment: Try with `/assets/...`

Comment: just tried, still not working, I've updated the picture in the question

Comment: Do you use webpack or an other bundler ?

Comment: I created the app by using "create-react-app" so I think that it has webpack as default, right?

Comment: The assets doc for create-react-app is [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/), sorry for not helping..

Comment: Thank you you helped me, I found a solution, will post it

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution,
after reading more I discovered that when using create-react-app you must use import (or require) and can't use img src="..." directly.
So I have edited the list of images to be like the following code, and now it work:

```
import BoschGBH11de from './BoschGBH11de.jpg';
import BoschHammer11 from './BoschHammer11.png';
import BoschHammerRental from './BoschHammerRental.jpg';

const photos = [
    {
        src: "https://source.unsplash.com/Dm-qxdynoEc/800x799",
        width: 4,
        height: 3
    },
    {
        src: BoschGBH11de,
        width: 4,
        height: 3
    },

    {
        src: BoschHammer11,
        width: 1,
        height: 1
    },
    {
        src: BoschHammerRental,
        width: 3,
        height: 4
    }
];

export default photos;
```